# How can I find the intersection of two lines in general equation form?

Tags: geometry

If I have six variables representing two lines in general equation form (ax + by + c = 0). So for example:

```
ax + by + c = 0
jx + ky + l = 0
```

How can I find the intersection point's (x and y) [assuming there is one] from the six variables?

PS. Any recommendation of a good source for information on very simply computational geometry, like this, would be appreciated.

Comment: As you are asking for an *equation*, this question should probably be on http://math.stackexchange.com/, not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The intersection point satisfies both equations. So all you need is to solve them simultaneously:

```
ax + by + c = 0    (*j)
jx + ky + l = 0    (*a)

ajx + bjy + cj = 0   (-)
ajx + aky + al = 0

(bj-ak)y + cj - al = 0

y = (al-cj) / (bj-ak)
```

And similarly for x. (Or you can substitute the found value for y in any of the original equations and then find x):

```
x = (ck-bl) / (bj-ak)
```

Comment: For: a1*x+b1*y+c1 = 0, a2*x+b2*y+c2 = 0; point.x = (c1*b2 - b1*c2)/(b1*a2 - a1*b2);  point.y =  (a1*c2 - a2*c1)/(b1*a2 - a1*b2)